# help with mushrooms identification

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I know that mushrooms identification is a difficult process. but I would like to ask for help in the identification of this one.

It growth over the grass in a backyard on Toronto, Canada.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you still have access to the mushrooms, it would be helpful to know the spore color. In case you're unfamiliar with how to find this out, you can take a 'spore print.' Remove the cap from the stem, place it on a piece of paper (or preferably aluminum foil), cover it with an upside-down glass, and wait at least 8 hours. The cap will deposit spores on the paper, and you will be able to see the color.

Comment: Amazing picture, by the way. These are very photogenic.

Comment: Added the spore print. Thank you for the instructions.

Comment: Brilliant. I would call that black from the picture, but do you see any tones in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a member of the genus [*Panaeolus*](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/panaeolus.html), based on the black spore print (distinguishing from *Psilocybe* and *Conocybe*), growth in grass (distinguishing from *Psathyrella* and *Naematoloma*), small stature and thin stem, bell-shaped cap, brown cap and gills, and lack of a ring on the stalk (David Arora, *Mushrooms Demystified*). The gills in the photo appear mottled to me, which is a diagnostic feature.

Unfortunately, species in this genus are especially difficult to identify. Michael Kuo writes on [*Mushroomexpert.com*](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/panaeolus.html):

> Beyond a few "easy" species, identification in *Panaeolus* requires microscopic examination, a good interlibrary loan desk, and the ability to read French and German.

[*Panaeolus foenisecii*](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/panaeolus_foenisecii.html) is a common member of this genus with macroscopic characteristics that match your specimens (see [*Mushroomexpert.com*](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/panaeolus_foenisecii.html) and [*MykoWeb*](https://www.mykoweb.com/CAF/species/Panaeolina_foenisecii.html) for detailed descriptions). The cap in this species changes color when waterlogged, which would be worth noting if you see it again. However, I am unsure of this ID without microscopic observation.

[image: Panaeolus foenisecii]
<sup>[*Panaeolus foenisecii*](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/panaeolus_foenisecii.html). Image: Michael Kuo, [*Mushroomexpert.Com*](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/).</sup>